# how set fixed where query in model laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My site has 5 languages
A column has been added for all tables with name `language`

How can be in the model of tables add `where('language' , App::getLocale())` query when use `select` data in database ?

**Scope** is one solution but another way

Thanks for  any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the newQuery() function on your Language Model (app\Models\Language.php)

```
/**
 * Get a new query builder for the model's table.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function newQuery()
{
    return parent::newQuery()->where('language', App::getLocale());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Global Scope and add scope to the `booted` method of model.

```
## App/Scopes/LanguageScope.php

<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class LanguageScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('language', App::getLocale());
    }
}
```

And in your model.

```
## App/Models/YourModel.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Scopes\LanguageScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YourModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new LanguageScope);
    }
}
```

So whenever you query records the `where` condition will be automatically added. You can read more about global scopes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes)